# Java - How to pass SSLSocket into vpnService.protect

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass the SSL Socket into vpnService.protect, but i'm getting an error.

Passing direct into method, my app crash after this.

Have an other way for to solve this?

Anyone may help me please, I need this so fast.